# erlang more efficient merge tuple list

Tags: erlang

I am looking for a way to be more efficient.

```
[{name, "Joe"}, {color, "Red"}, {file, "none"}] => {name,"Joe",color,"Red",file,"none"}.

list_to_tuple(lists:flatten([tuple_to_list(X1) || X1 <- L]))
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. 
As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
list_to_tuple([X || T <- L, X <- tuple_to_list(T)])).
```

or

```
list_to_tuple([X || {K, V} <- L, X <- [K, V]]).
```

or more explicit and probably most efficient

```
merge_tuple_list(L) -> list_to_tuple(merge_tuple_list_(L)).

merge_tuple_list_([{K, V} | T]) -> [K, V | merge_tuple_list_(T) ];
merge_tuple_list_([])           -> [].
```

Comment: The last one is definitely the best, trying to use HO just becomes convoluted in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe

`list_to_tuple(lists:flatten([K, V] || {K, V} <- L])).`